# Watij’s JxBrowser OS X / Java 1.6_64 incompatibility?

Tags: java, macos, 64-bit, watij, jxbrowser

I tried to install and use [Watij](http://watij.com/) (Web Application Testing in Java) on my OS X 10.6 system.

However, when trying to run a sample test, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Error:
JxBrowser library doesn't support current operation system:

OS: Mac OS X
OS architecture: x86_64
Java vendor: Apple Inc.
Java version: 1.6.0_31
Execution data model: 64-bit

    at com.teamdev.awtinteraction.a.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.xpcom.MacXPCOMMessageLoopThread.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamdev.xpcom.MacXPCOMMessageLoopThread.<init>(Unknown Source)
    [stack trace continues]
```

Suspecting a 64-bit issue, I used the Java preferences app to switch the JVM to default to 32 bits execution. However, the error message is strictly the same.

Does anyone think of a way to solve this issue, either by making sure the 32 bits JVM is chosen, or by knowing which other environment element would remove the incompatibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the -d32 to your VM parameters.

Comment: Or, with ant, add `<jvmarg value="-d32"/>` as a nested node inside the `<java>` task.